# Jquery not getting value from EditorFor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, editorfor

I have this on my partial view

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DirectorsEntity.ApplicationDate, new { @class = "form-control", @id="appdate" })
```

in my jquery I have:

```
var appdate = $("#appdate").val();
```

Unfortunately it is coming back as undefined.

I change my EditorFor to TextBox for, it works but I really prefer to use EditorFor. Does anyone have any idea why one would work and the other doesn't?

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DirectorsEntity.ApplicationDate, new { @class = "form-control", @id="appdate" })
```

Comment: Because `EditorFor()` does not allow your to add html attributes unless you using MVC-5.1 or higher, and if you are, then its not the correct format anyway (refer the dupe). Your `EditorFor()` is generating `id="DirectorsEntity_ApplicationDate"`, so just use `var appdate = $("#"DirectorsEntity_ApplicationDate").val();`

Answer (score 1):

if you use 'Editorfor' as in the following **Code1** example, It generates an input text element with id & name set to property name as in **Code2** example.

Code1 :

```
 @Html.EditorFor(m => m.UserName)
```

Code2:

```
 <input class="text-box single-line" id="UserName" name="UserName" type="text" value="">
```

If you use separate id for 'Editorfor', it won't work since its taking the default id. Use property name in id selection in jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try this?

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DirectorsEntity.ApplicationDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control",@id= "appdate" } })
```